supabase_vector_container is not ready: unhealthy
I want to set up supabase locally host on windows, i have downloaded and installed docker. I first tried
--- # Get the code
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/supabase/supabase

# Go to the docker folder
cd supabase/docker

# Copy the fake env vars
cp .env.example .env

# Pull the latest images
docker compose pull

# Start the services (in detached mode)
docker compose up -d

it didn't work. Then i used
scoop bucket add supabase https://github.com/supabase/scoop-bucket.git
scoop install supabase

but after running these commands, i got an error when i run supabase init
2024-09-25T14:12:08.141952Z  INFO vector::app: All sources have finished.
                                                 2024-09-25T14:12:08.141974Z  INFO vector: Vector has stopped.
                                                                                                              2024-09-25T14:12:08.143702Z  INFO vector::topology::running: Shutting down... Waiting on running components. remaining_components="logflare_kong, logflare_storage, logflare_db, logflare_realtime, logflare_functions, logflare_auth, logflare_rest" time_remaining="59 seconds left"
                            Stopping containers...
supabase_vector_hisri container is not ready: unhealthy
Try rerunning the command with --debug to troubleshoot the error.

Error after running supabase init --debug
2024/09/25 14:48:45 Recv First Byte
                                                                                    Stopping containers...
Pruned containers: [b6b5d6103eccd0c5d323ca5db9ae046a6215041584ee55f6ea34fcbf2c0a8052 f6174510124082b4cb31503040fd8c8ede7bd7ff6e59a98f04dae7fad1fd7e7b 561670bc4ce307632f85a4be3a15929ef9b45bc07cd5a04c315e04a876750a30]
Pruned volumes: [supabase_db_hisri supabase_config_hisri]
Pruned network: [supabase_network_hisri]
failed to create docker container: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/supabase_vector_hisri" is already in use by container "561670bc4ce307632f85a4be3a15929ef9b45bc07cd5a04c315e04a876750a30". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

i have looked for commands to remove everything and re-install but all the commands i get didn't remove a thing. In fact there were not recognized by windows, those commands.

did you resolve this error? I have exactly the same problem

I had the same problem and what solved it for me was clearing the cache within docker. I had a problem starting a container and it didn't close properly so when I reran the program and got that error. So if you also have had a problem running that before running into that error then you probably need to clear your docker cache. You can access that in the debug tab in docker desktop.
